# How do I darken colors in a MPandroidchart pie chart in night mode?

Tags: android, android-studio, pie-chart, mpandroidchart, android-night-mode

I am creating an Andriod app with sqlite database. I am using MPandroidchart for data visualization. In the pie chart, I was able to tweak everything except the display of colors in the night theme. The colors in the legend are darkened as they would normally in night mode. But the colors on the donut are still vibrant. I just can't fix it. Who can help?

```
fun drawClientsChart(
    chart: PieChart,
    data: ArrayList<ListItemAnalyticClients>,
    withConsult: Boolean = false,
    withAnimation: Boolean = true
) {

    ...
    val hsv = FloatArray(3)
    hsv[1] = 0.5f // Saturation 0-1
    hsv[2] = 0.89f // Brightness 0-1

    for (i in 0 until data.size) {
        ...
        hsv[0] = (330 * i/data.size).toFloat()
        colors.add(Color.HSVToColor(hsv))
    }
    ...
    catsSet.colors = colors
    ...
    pieData.setValueTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white, context.theme))
    ...
    chart.setHoleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    ...
}
```

Screenshots:
[day mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU6Pc.jpg),
[night mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIkYy.jpg)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can see you're using color resources. Simply add colors.xml for night mode and change colors in that file.

Comment: @Community, I did it.

Comment: @qki, I tried to do this, but it didn't work to me.